# Rectangular table with diagonal arrows

Tags: tables, matrices, arrows

I'm trying to make a kind of matrix with text in its cells and arrows in its diagonal. How can I make a rectangle table like this one in LaTeX?

[image]

I've made this so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{llcc}
 &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Job Demands}}           \\
 &  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Low} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{High} \\ \cline{3-4} 
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Job Decision Latitude}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Low} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Passive \\ Job\end{tabular}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{High Strain Job} \\ \cline{3-4} 
 &
 \multicolumn{1}{l|}{High} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Low Strain \\ Job\end{tabular}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Active \\ Job\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{3-4} 
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But I don't know how to make the diagonal arrows

Comment: This question is duplicate to your previous question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561803/rectangle-cell-tables-with-text-and-arrows) , which receive answer with good solution. It will be better that you edit your previous question and add code provided here there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `tikz`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  plainnode/.style={
    outer sep=0pt,
    inner sep=0pt
  },
  fwtextnode/.style={
    fill=white,
    minimum width=2.5cm,
    text width=2.5cm,
    execute at begin node={\scriptsize\centering},
    execute at end node={\par}
  },
  textnode/.style={
    execute at begin node={\scriptsize}
  }
}

\newcommand*{\textloc}{0.4}

% node a
% node b
% coef
% text
% option
\newcommand{\interpnode}[5]{
  \node[textnode,#5] at ($(#1)+#3*(#2)-#3*(#1)$) {#4};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (-4, 2);
\coordinate (b) at (4, 2);
\coordinate (c) at (4, -2);
\coordinate (d) at (-4, -2);
\coordinate (e) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (b1) at (5, 2.5);
\coordinate (c1) at (5, -2.5);
\coordinate (f) at ($0.5*(a)+0.5*(b)+(0cm,1cm)$);

\draw[thick] (a)--(b)--(c)--(d)--(a);
\draw[thick] ($0.5*(a)+0.5*(d)$)--($0.5*(b)+0.5*(c)$);
\draw[thick] ($0.5*(a)+0.5*(b)$)--($0.5*(d)+0.5*(c)$);
\draw[thick] (a)--(e);
\draw[thick] (b)--(e);
\draw[thick] (c)--(e);
\draw[thick] (d)--(e);
\draw[thick,-latex] (b)--(b1);
\draw[thick,-latex] (c)--(c1);

\node at (f) {\textbf{Job Demands}};
\node[fwtextnode] at ($\textloc*(a)$) {\uppercase{``passive''\\ job}};
\node[fwtextnode] at ($\textloc*(b)$) {\uppercase{``high strain''\\ job}};
\node[fwtextnode] at ($\textloc*(c)$) {\uppercase{``active''\\ job}};
\node[fwtextnode] at ($\textloc*(d)$) {\uppercase{``low strain''\\ job}};
\node[fwtextnode,text width=1.5cm, minimum width=1.5cm, xshift=1.0cm] at (b1) {Unresolved\\ Strain};
\node[fwtextnode,text width=1.5cm, minimum width=1.5cm, xshift=1.0cm] at (c1) {Activity\\ Level};

\interpnode{a}{d}{0.25}{Low}{anchor=east}
\interpnode{a}{d}{0.75}{High}{anchor=east}
\interpnode{a}{d}{0.5}{Job Decision Latitude}{anchor=east,xshift=-3mm}
\interpnode{b}{c}{0.25}{A}{anchor=west,xshift=3mm}
\interpnode{b}{c}{0.75}{B}{anchor=west,xshift=3mm}
\interpnode{a}{b}{0.25}{Low}{anchor=south}
\interpnode{a}{b}{0.75}{High}{anchor=south}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

A comparatively short code with `pstricks`:

```
 \documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage{pst-eucl}%
 \usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} 

 \begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(-7.58,-3)(7,3)\sffamily\small
    \psset{ PointName=none, arrowinset=0.12, linejoin=1}%unit =1.5cm,
    \pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none](0,0){c}(0,-2){b}(-4,-2){A}(-4,0){l}(-4,2){B}(0,2){t}(4,2){C}(4,0){r}(4,-2){D}
    \psframe(A)(C)\ncline{t}{b}\ncline{l}{r}
    % border labels
    \psset{linestyle =none}
    \ncline{l}{B}\naput{Low}\ncline{B}{t}\naput{Low}
    \ncline{C}{r}\naput{\qquad A}\ncline{r}{D}\naput{\qquad B}
    \ncline{A}{l}\naput{High}\ncline{t}{C}\naput{Hi\smash{g}h}%
    \uput[l](l){Job Decision Latitude \quad}
    %%% Diagonals & labels
    \psset{nodesepB=-1, linestyle=solid}
    \ncline{A}{c}\ncput*{\Centerstack{"LOW STRAIN"\\ JOB}}
    \ncline{B}{c}\ncput*{\Centerstack{"PASSIVE"\\ JOB}}
    \psset{arrows =->, nodesepB =-1.3,npos=0.3}
    \pstLineAB{c}{C}\ncput*{\Centerstack{"HIGH STRAIN"\\ JOB}}
     \uput[r](5.2, 2.6){\Centerstack{Unresolved\\ Strain}}
    \pstLineAB{c}{D}\ncput*{\Centerstack{"ACTIVE"\\ JOB}}
    \uput[r](5.2, -2.6){\Centerstack{Activity\\ Level}}
    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]